# How do you solve the system given the contraint?

Tags: calculus

Using lagrange i got something like $$3x = 4z = 6y$$

And the constraint is $$z^2 = x^2 + y^2$$

Where do you get from here?

I usually get $x=y=z$, but here i got $3$ variables with different values.

Comment: What's the system you're trying to solve? Since you mention Lagrange, it seems more likely that you're trying to optimize a function given a constraint.

Comment: To add up to the comment above, the problem as written now given these two simultaneous equations has a single trivial solution: $x=y=z=0$.

Comment: ah, actually it is -6z = -8x = 3y

Comment: is there a way to solve this, like a method? or do you think i've made a mistake somehow?

Comment: You haven't given the actual problem you are trying to solve. But there is only only solution to the equations you gave above, as is mentioned about and below.

Comment: 4x-3y+8z=5 given the constraint z^2 = x^2 + y^2

Comment: What do you mean by that? Both equations have the form of constraints. Are you minimizing or maximizing something?

Comment: i need to find the extreme values of f(x) = 4z-3y+8z=5

Comment: Your next-to-last comment should be part of the question-it is what you (seem to) really want.  But neither one is the function you want to maximize, they are both constraints (see the equal sign).

Answer (score 1):

The only solution to that system is $x=y=z=0$. Use $z=\frac{3}{4}x,y=\frac{1}{2}x$ and substitute into the constraint. The only solution is $x=0$, and the other variables follow.

Comment: if x is 0, y and z should be 0 too.

Comment: Yes, I believe I wrote that the only solution is $x= y=z=0$?